# What to put inside __init__ method in django form class?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

When does one usually use a `__init__` function in a django form, because I do not seem to ever need to have an `__init__` function inside of a form. Usually, I can just create a form with fields that are inherited from `forms` for example `forms.charfield`. So, when would one actually need to use an `__init__` function.

Comment: Changed question. Hopefully better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time it is not necessary to *override*  the `__init__` function - note that it already is defined in the base form class.

If you ever need to override it, make sure you call the super object's `__init__` function, or you'll break stuff big-time.

I found that the most common use-case to override the `__init__` method is to define or exclude fields dynamically, based on some condition. This would look like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FormClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.object: # in case of ModelForm
        self.fields['extra_field'] = forms.CharField(required=False)
        self.fields['other_field'].required = True
        del(self.fields['non_editable_field'])
```